# Get custom attribute of simple products that are saleable

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, collection

I have a collection of products which consist of configurable products that are visible and active.

How do i get all values in an array of an attribute called `manu_color` of each configurable product.

I is important that i only get `manu_color` of the simple products if the simple product are actually saleable.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so far i have this. Problem is that array return identical values.
Will post update when i have it working 100%

```
if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"):
            $conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
            $simple_collection = $conf
                ->getUsedProductCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                ->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
                Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($simple_collection);
            $manuColor = array();
            foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){
                $manu_color[] = $simple_product->getAttributeText('manu_color');
            }
        endif;
```